# How to get openai completion call to both return the function name and answer the question using the information already available?

Tags: openai-api

Looks like the openai completion API returns one or the other: it will either answer the question or it will return a function to call. I can't have it both ways in one prompt. For example, the following prompt returns information about weather patterns in Boston:

Prompt:

```
{
    messages: {  "role": "user", "content": "Tell me about the weather in Boston }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  role: 'assistant',
  content: 'The weather in Boston can vary greatly depending on the season. Summers in Boston are typically....
}
```

However if I provide it with a function, openai will return the function to call and nothing else.

Prompt:

```
{
    messages: {  "role": "user", "content": "Tell me about the weather in Boston }
    functions: [ {  name: "get_weather_info", description: "Get weather information"}]
}
```

Response:

```
{
  role: 'assistant',
  content: null,<-------How to include the general weather information here
  function_call: {
    name: 'get_weather_info',
    arguments: '{\n  "location": "Boston"\n}'
  }
}
```